# How to differentiate between USB and SD mount?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-broadcastreceiver, usb-drive, removable-storage

I have an Android 6.0 phone with internal memory, removable SD card and USB OTG (pen-drive with micro USB jack) inserted in the phone. Removable SD card and USB OTG was ejected in Android equipment: "Settings" -> "Storage & USB". I can mount removable SD card and USB OTG in this equipment. For example, I mount removable SD and want to differentiate this event from mounting of USB OTG. The only action I can get in the receiver

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.RemovableMediaReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL"/>

            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

on mount is **android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED** and path to root of mounted SD card as an extra to this action - */storage/A13D-EF43*. The same situation is for USB OTG mounting event. The only difference is in the name of mounted USB OTG - path is */storage/BD76-24ED*.

How can I understand which media was mounted - SD or USB OTG - if I have no API call to get a name of SD or USB OTG before mounting in order to compare it with extra (path) from **android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED**?

Comment: Did you ever figure something out for this @isabsent?

Comment: No. Let me know if you find.